# Where is the performance bottleneck in this Spark/Scala code?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

First of all let me point out that I am quite new to both Spark and Scala. I have being trying to investigate the promised Spark performance by trying to migrate one of the Hadoop Map/Reduce Jobs I have done in the past. This job takes 14 minutes on Hadoop using 3x r3.2xlarge machines for an input of 16 compressed bzip files of 170mb each. I translated it to Scala/Spark the best that I could into something like this:

```
val conceptData = spark.textFile(inputPath)
val result = conceptData.repartition(60).cache()
    .map(line => {val metrics = JsonUtil.fromJson[ArticleMetrics](line); (metrics.source, metrics.data.get("entities").get)})
    .flatMap(metrics => metrics._2.map(t => (t._1,(1,List((metrics._1,t._2.head))))))
    .reduceByKey((a,b) => combine(a,b))
    .map(t => t._1 + "\t" + t._2._1 + "\t" + print(t._2._2))
result.saveAsTextFile(outputPath)

def print(tuples: List[(String, Any)]): String =
{
  tuples.map(l => l._1 + "\u200e" + l._2).reduce(_ + "\u200f" + _)
}

def combine(a: (Int, List[(String, Any)]), b: (Int, List[(String, Any)])): (Int, List[(String, Any)]) =
{
  (a._1 + b._1,a._2 ++ b._2)
}

object JsonUtil {
  val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
  mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
  mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)

  def fromJson[T](json: String)(implicit m : Manifest[T]): T = {
    mapper.readValue[T](json)
  }
}
```

I used the repartition command at the beginning to set the partitions to 60 since I read somewhere that is good to have 2-3 partitions per core.
I am running this Spark job on the same 3x r3.2xlarge machines (each has 8 cores and 58G available) so I submit my job in the following manner:

```
spark/bin/spark-submit --executor-memory 58G --total-executor-cores 24 (... other arguments ...)
```

And it took more than 1 hour to run through the same input... I am not sure if the problem is in the Scala or Spark configuration so any help is welcome.

Best regards,
Augusto

**EDIT 1:** Average times for some operations:

Reading the files from S3: ~ 2minutes

flatMap: ~ 11 minutes

reduceByKey: > 1 hour

The keys used are S3 paths so they can get quite long, don't know if that makes a difference.

**EDIT 2:** I substituted the `reduceByKey` function with `.reduceByKey((a,b) => a)` and the job ends under 10min so there must be something really wrong with the `combine` function

Comment: Few questions. 1. Can you tell the version of Spark you are using ? 2. I'm assuming you are running in Standalone mode. 3. Have you looked at the Spark UI. What does it say ? Finally, did you try to run each of these operations from the Scala REPL ? 

You can do that by breaking down your first line. Spark is much faster than this. A quick look at your code tells that you are just parsing around 3G of data and running a MR on it. If you are using Spark 1.1+ you can load `conceptData` as a SparkSQL table and then read the value there and see how long it takes.

Comment: 1) Spark 1.2 2) Standalone 3) The UI indicated that until the flatMap line, execution took about 7 minutes, it was after most of the time was spent.

Comment: How about just doing the following on the REPL. `val conceptData = spark.textFile(inputPath)` followed by `conceptData.count` and see how long it takes. You should use the same settings from your Scala REPL (i.e., spark/bin/spark-shell --executor-memory 58G ..) I'm also assuming you are loading from HDFS locally (on EC2).

Comment: You shouldn't `.cache()` something you're only using once. And I wouldn't manually `repartition` until you're sure you need to. How does it perform without any repartitioning?

Comment: @SoumyaSimanta - I am loading the data from S3. I will try that when I have the opportunity but I believe the loading of the files doesn't take long.

Comment: @lmm - I chose to repartition manually because being the input 16 files, the partition was set to 16 so not all the cores were used while running the job.

Comment: I don't think that `repartition` will actually help you here, since in this case it will probably trigger a full shuffle.  This job is already IO-bound, so I don't think you'll see a large speed-up by shuffling data in order to gain extra parallelism.  You may want to have a higher degree of parallelism in `reduceByKey()`, though.

Comment: The part of loading the files and the flatMap does not take long - using reduceByKey with 24 partitions still takes more than 1 hour.

Comment: I substituted the `reduceByKey` function with `.reduceByKey((a,b) => a)` and the job takes in under 10min so there must be something really bad with the `combine` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This came down to my noobish Scala programming skills - it takes only 15 min when changed to the following more performant Scala:

```
val conceptData = spark.textFile(inputPath).repartition(24)

val result = conceptData.map(line => {val metrics = JsonUtil.fromJson[ArticleMetrics](line); (metrics.source, metrics.data.get("entities").get)})
    .flatMap(metrics => metrics._2.map(t => (t._1,(1, List(metrics._1+"\u200e"+ t._2.head)))))
    .reduceByKey((a,b) =>  (a._1 + b._1, a._2:::b._2))
    .map(t=> t._1 + "\t" + t._2._1 + "\t" + t._2._2.mkString("\u200f"))
```

It can probably still be further improved. Anyway, thanks for the help everybody.

Best regards,

Augusto

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that most of the time is spent after the flatMap, I would suspect that the shuffle is what slowing you down and not CPU utilization. You might want to try with running the job with fewer partitions. Another thing you can try is to replace the `reduceByKey()` with `foldByKey()` which is associative but not commutative which means it has to keep the RDDs order when running the combine, and this might translate to less network traffic during the shuffle.

Comment: I tried using foldByKey and the job dies if I use that. I tried it twice and it happened at the same moment in time (after 27 min( - the only error message I can find is: `executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated`